# Deleting duplicates row from a table in Access DB

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a query that will delete all the duplicates row from an *Access 2010* table. And **my problem is that the query is deleting all the duplicate records (even original)**.

So let say I have 1 record that is original and 2 records that are duplicates, so incited deleting 2 duplicates it deleting all 3.

Here is what i did:

```
DELETE *
    FROM Table
    WHERE [field1] IN (SELECT [field1] FROM [table] As Tmp 
    GROUP BY [field1],[field2],[field3],[field4],[field5] HAVING Count(*)>1);
```

Any advice please, and thank you.

Comment: Find Duplicates Query Wizard it will give you all dups and you have to clean it your self, i want to automate it.

Comment: Does the table include an autonumber primary key field?  If not, can you add one?

Comment: No, and Unfortunately I can't add one

Comment: You need add a unique id all records, if not already have one, and then you can delete all duplicates except the first one.

Comment: So there is no way to do it with out this field?

Comment: Say you have two rows with the same values.  You want to delete one, not both.  Without a primary key, there is no SQL way to tell Access to delete one but not the other.  (At least no practical way that I'm aware of.)  It would be possible with a VBA procedure, but you're asking for a query.

Comment: How to do it if Have a Primary key?

Answer (score 0):

These commands should work in a standard SQL server.  You'll have to test it to see if Access does anything funny to it.

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT field1, field2,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field1)
   FROM table1
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE *
   FROM Table
   WHERE [UniqueField] NOT IN (SELECT MIN([UniqueField]) FROM [table] As Tmp 
   GROUP BY [field1],[field2],[field3],[field4],[field5] HAVING Count(*)>1);
```

It should works on MS-ACCESS too.

Comment: Didn't work. It deleting all unique fields and leaving all dups

Comment: @Amiaki I made an edit to my post (i forgotten the MIN). Did you try with the `MIN(...)` expression?

Comment: Same result as the first one

Comment: @Amiaki What returns: `SELECT MIN([UniqueField]) FROM [table] As Tmp 
   GROUP BY [field1],[field2],[field3],[field4],[field5] HAVING Count(*)>1`

Comment: Giving me a warning that it about to delete 88 rows, which is rows that don't have any dups, and without MIN(...) it leaving 88 rows (that don't have any dups) and if row got at least 1 dup it deleting both out, and need to take out only dups

Comment: @Amiaki do You do the MIN function in an unique key? For example your primary key?